# Resources in Package.swift generated xcodeproject

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, xcode13

I need a workspace or project of Package.swift from the terminal.  I know
`xed.` can be used to open package.xcworspace. But to work in CI environment I am not sure if it is right cause xed. cannot work headless.

The other option I am left with is generating xcodeproject

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

But the above does not include resources (like .json) references in the generated project.

Any of the following could help

1. Any third-party tool to add resources to generated xcodeproject from the command line
2. Any ways to generate package.xcworkspace without xed. from command line